# Is there a way to ignore isset and display result

Tags: php, html

May be is something easy but can't understand this.

I have two pages which both lead to third page. 
In third page I have

```
if(isset($_GET['something']) && isset($_GET['somethingelse']))
{
     $something = $_GET['something'];
     $somethingelse = $_GET['somethingelse'];
     //more stuff here
}
```

From `page1.php` to `page3.php` one the url is like

```
<a href="page3.php?something='.$something.'&somethingelse='.$somethingelse.'">Click</a>
```

and the page3.php show everything as expected. The problem is from `page2.php` to `page3.php`. There the link is like

```
<a href="page3.php?something='.$something.'">Click</a>
```

So page3.php doesn't load properly since there is check for `somethingelse`.. How can I ignore isset without to delete it because I need that value of `$somethingelse` but only when it comes from `page1.php`. I just can't think for properly solution here.

Comment: You forgot to add `$_GET` change to `isset($_GET['somethingelse'])`

Comment: Yes, thank's. It's because I didn't copy this..Anyway, can you help with the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just ignore an if statement, that is the whole point of flow control. You only want to do something, if it's passed the if statement. If you only want to define $somethingelse if it's in the $_GET variable, and allow the script to continue executing if $_GET['somethingelse'] is empty, then:

```
if(isset($_GET['something'])) {
     $something = $_GET['something'];
     $somethingelse = $_GET['somethingelse'] ?: false;
     //more stuff here
}
```

Comment: It's exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

make it separate:

```
if(isset($_GET['something']))
{
     $something = $_GET['something'];
     //more stuff here
}
if(isset($_GET['somethingelse']))
{
     $somethingelse = $_GET['somethingelse'];
     //some more stuff here
}
```

because, when `somethingelse` is not set `$something = $_GET['something']` wont happen neither

Comment: I was thinking of that, but it looked like he DID only want the page to do something if 'something' is defined. Hard to tell though from the question phrasing.

Comment: Thank's but this will require to make same source code twice. Which is not and option.